# Where can I find more information about the Kel'Dor?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars, star-wars-age-of-rebellion

I'm joining a Star Wars Pen & Paper Roleplay Group. I already generated my character with the GM; a Kel'Dor. I was searching in the rulebooks we have for more information about the Kel'Dor and their culture and so on but the core rulebooks and the Ultimate Alien Anthology books provide way too little information. I've already read the articles on wookie/jedipedia.

Does anyone know where I could find detailed information about the Kel'Dor?

Comment: Looks like this belongs in the [Science Fiction & Fantasy StackExchange](http://scifi.stackexchange.com). The question is clearly about the fictional species and not the game.

Comment: We take e.g. Forgotten Realms questions even though there are many novels set there too. Poster is asking for info for a character, which seems on-topic.

Comment: @fectin The difference is this is a real-world research question (in a sense): ctrl+f our [on topic help page](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for the phrase "real-world topic". These kinds of questions are off topic because they are not relevant to our expertise whatsoever; the asker is explicitly searching for information beyond the bounds of any RPG material. An RPG expert would not give a better, different, or more specific answer than a non-RPG-playing star wars or sci-fi fan. FR meanwhile is a setting inherently part of RPGs, which makes it actually relevant to our expertise.

Answer (score 3):

The best, easy to access source for StarWars material is often the [Wookiepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kel_Dor). make sure to check the "Legends" part as well as the "Canon" part, due to the Disney-Canon-Wipe.

as you said, the old [StarWars d20 Alien Anthology](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_Anthology) and [Ultimate Alien Anthology](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Alien_Anthology) has a little splat on them - generally any place listed in the [Wookiepedia Sources](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kel_Dor/Legends#Sources) holds some information on them

Answer (score 1):

This article goes a little more into their biology, but not too terribly much. Wookipedia tends to be very thorough, so you may not find much more in the way of general information.

I would recommend coming up with specific questions and asking either here or in the sci-fi exchange.

http://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Kel_Dor